# Android - Make my own layout of Preference

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences

I need to use SharedPreference for saving login, password and a other string in my application, but i don't want to use the default layout's preference.

I have already read the documentation of SharedPref : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#ReadingPrefs

But.. hum.
I've create a class named preferences_dashboard.
In this class, if a checkbow is checked, i backup login etc, and if the checkbox is not checked, i delete the backup.

There is my code :

```
public void saveID(View v) {

    // strMessage is the message with appears when clicking on Checkbox
    String strMessage = "";

    CheckBox chkBoxSaveID;
    chkBoxSaveID = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.preferencecheckBoxSaveID);
    boolean chkBoxSaveIDState = chkBoxSaveID.isChecked();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit(); // Put the values from the UI

    if (chkBoxSaveID.isChecked()) {

        // Backup LOGIN

        String userLogin ="Administrator2";
        String userPassword = "password2";
        String userDomain = "12";

        editor.putString("KEY_USER_LOGIN", userLogin); // Storing string
        editor.putString("KEY_USER_PASSWORD", userPassword); // Storing string
        editor.putString("KEY_USER_DOMAIN", userDomain); // Storing string
        editor.putBoolean("stateChkBoxMemorizeID", chkBoxSaveIDState); // value to store
        editor.commit(); // commit changes

        strMessage += "ID memorized" + "KEY_USER_DOMAIN" + userPassword + userDomain;
        showTextNotification(strMessage);
    } else {

        // No backup LOGIN
        editor.remove("KEY_USER_LOGIN"); // will delete key name
        editor.remove("KEY_USER_PASSWORD");
        editor.remove("KEY_USER_DOMAIN");
        editor.putBoolean("stateChkBoxMemorizeID", chkBoxSaveIDState); // value to store
        editor.commit(); // commit changes

        strMessage += "Login is not memorized ";
        showTextNotification(strMessage);
    }
} // end saveID
```

I think i don't really understand how use SharedPreferences.
String Login/Pass/Domain are fixed for the test. After, i will recup variables on a other activity.

My question :

1. Where these variables will be backup ? In data/date/nameappli/xml generated ? Or in the defaultSharedPreference ?
2. What i have missed ? :(

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("customSharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In this way, you have a seperate SharedPreferences to store the information you want. And you can name it anything. Just pass the name as a string like here I used `"customSharedPrefs"`.
Thus, you can create multiple `SharedPreferences` with different names.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answere.
So, after, for edit, i need this : SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit(); and editor.putString("KEY_USER_LOGIN", userLogin); will create a entry named "KEY_USER_LOGIN" with the value userLogin ?

Comment: Yes. That will do it. And it will be stored, in this `customSharedPrefs` `SharedPreference`. And dont forget to use editor.apply();

Comment: Already did but i miss reputations, it does't work, stackoverflow refuse my opinion :)